# Google Voice missing from app drawer after upgrading to ICS

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, google-voice

I upgraded from 2.3 a few months ago, but didn't notice that Google Voice was missing from the  app drawer. The market lists the application as installed, but does not give me an option to open the app.

[image: Screen Shot]

How do I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you to Settings --> Apps --> All, is it in the list of applications?  If so, click on it, click Uninstall, and then try to reinstall it from the market.

It's also possible that the market is incorrectly showing it as installed.  If this is the case, try going to Settings --> Apps --> All --> Market, click Force Stop, then Clear data.  The open the market again and see if Google Voice is still listed as installed, and if not, install it.

Comment: I looked up the Market and found that there was no data to clear. But I was able to uninstall an update to the market, which I did. Restarted the Market and found GV pending an update. All was well after the update to GV. Thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 0):

Check the app drawer again -- it's listed (alphabetically) under "Voice", not "Google Voice".